# WebGL: Every second triangle is missing

Tags: javascript, webgl

It seems that every second triangle of a 3d object is missing. For example when a cube is drawn, there are only 6 triangles, one on each face. [Here is a picture of the problem](http://vgstuff.com/myrandompics/triangleproblem.png). This problem persists even if only one object is drawn.

Here are parts of my code where I think the problem might be:

```
//start up
gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
gl.clearDepth(1.0);
//shaders
//vertexShader
'
    attribute vec3 vertexPosition;
    uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
    attribute vec2 uv;
    varying vec2 vUV;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = transformationMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition,1);
        vUV = uv;
    }'
//fragmentShader
//problem is still there even when not using a texture
'
    precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D sampler;
    varying vec2 vUV;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler,vUV);
    }'
//after shaders are compiled and some getAttribLocation/enableVertex/AttribLocation/etc calls are made, models and textures are loaded
//each model has a vertexBuffer, indexBuffer, and nIndices, among some other things
//models are retrieved in a for loop
//models are exported to json format with a vertex format of [X,Y,Z,Nx,Ny,Nz,U,V]

var retrievedModel = retrieveResourceFile(resourcesToLoad.models[m].source);

//make vertex buffer

resourcesToLoad.models[m].path.vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,resourcesToLoad.models[m].path.vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(retrievedModel.vertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

//make index buffer

resourcesToLoad.models[m].path.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,resourcesToLoad.models[m].path.indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,new Uint16Array(retrievedModel.indices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
resourcesToLoad.models[m].path.nIndices = retrievedModel.indices.length;

//now in draw loop, objects that need to be drawn are stored in Draw.objectsToRender array

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,Draw.objectsToRender[i].model.vertexBuffer);

gl.vertexAttribPointer(Shaders.modelShaderProgram.vertexPosition,3,gl.FLOAT,false,4*(3+3+2),0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(Shaders.modelShaderProgram.uv,2,gl.FLOAT,false,4*(3+3+2),(3+3)*4);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,Draw.objectsToRender[i].model.indexBuffer);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES,Draw.objectsToRender[i].model.nIndices,gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
```

I've been comparing my code to a tutorial I used http://www.webglacademy.com/#6, (particularly part 6 section 8), and I can't spot anything different that would cause this problem. The models I am using were exported from Blender using the export script provided in part 6 of the tutorial, but I don't think there is a problem there, as I tried using the dragon model data that works fine in the tutorial, and it has the missing triangles problem when used with my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am gonna take a swing in the dark here since it has been a while since I did webGl. This looks like the draw order of your triangles is wrong. In other words, the triangles are drawing, but they are drawn facing away from the camera (which makes them appear invisible!) For more info google the left hand rule. My suggestion is to change from TRIANGLES to TRIANGLE_STRIP and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately I didn't really see anything about the left hand rule that could fix this problem, and using TRIANGLE_STRIP made the shapes look odd.

Comment: Looks like your meshes are not triangulated. Try export a cube and see if all 12 faces are indexed correctly in the JSON file.

Comment: Thanks LJ_1102, going into Blender and triangulating the model, then exporting it worked. Well, it at least worked for the cube, which now has all its faces, but for the aircraft, it still has the problem. I tried triangulating it and exporting it multiple times, but it doesn't seem to work. I had to enable the OES element index uint for it to show properly because it has so many vertices, maybe that could have something to do with the problem? I don't know enough about Blender to know if there's anything else I can do in it to possibly fix it. At least it was a step in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution. Using the older version of blender that the tutorials used(2.63, I was using 2.72b) helped with one other model, then finally I got the aircraft to show up correctly, though not as good looking, by turning off a subsurface modifier that was being applied to the model. So doing those things, and triangulating, makes everything render fine with no missing triangles problem. Thanks for the help, Chris and LJ.